# Finding the probability of drawing a heart from a deck of cards.

Tags: probability

So let's say I roll a 4 sided die. Whatever number it lands on is the number of cards I have to draw from a standard 52 card deck. So if it lands on a 3 then I have to pick up 3 cards. I win if I get a heart. What is the probability of not winning after I play once? There's 13 hearts out of 52 cards so I assume I have a 0.25 probability of drawing a heart but how can I use the dice roll to figure out what my chances are of losing the game on my first try?

Comment: You roll a one and you lose OR you roll a two and you lose OR you roll a three...

Comment: So would I be correct in saying there's a 0.0625 chance of rolling a one and winning which means there's a 0.9375 chance I'll roll a one and lose?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well that's just for rolling a one. I assume that if I have to add up the probabilities for rolling a 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 1):

There are four possibilities for your dice roll.

These possibilities are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

We also need the probability of drawing $n$ cards and not getting a heart. For 1 card this will be $(52-13)/52$, for two cards this will be $\frac{(52-13)}{52}\cdot \frac{(51-13)}{51} = \frac{39\cdot38}{52\cdot51}$, etc.

So for $n$ cards this will be $$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(40-i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(53-i)}$$

So now our probability is simply the sum of the probabilities of the dice rolls multiplied by their corresponding card drawing probabilities, which are all $\frac{1}{4}$.

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4\bigg[ \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k}(40-i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{k}(53-i)}\bigg] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4\prod_{i=1}^{k}\bigg[ \frac{(40-i)}{(53-i)}\bigg]$$

Comment: Be careful.  $51 - 13 = \color{red}{38}$.

Comment: Right you are! How's that

Comment: It is not quite right.  Notice that if $n = 1$, $$\frac{\prod_{i = 39 - n}^{39} i}{\prod_{i = 52 - n}^{52} i} = \frac{38}{51}$$  Instead of subtracting $i$ from $39$, you need to subtract $i - 1$, giving $39 - (i - 1) = 40 - i$, and similarly for the index in the denominator.  Personally, I would write the product in the numerator as $$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} (40 - k)$$ to convey that the factors in the numerator are decreasing from $39$ to $39 - (k - 1) = 40 - k$.

Comment: I simplified the product at the end as well